# Nivo slider transitions aren't working correctly

Tags: jquery, wordpress, nivo-slider

I'm using the nivo slider jQuery plugin in my wordpress theme (that's right, I'm using the jQuery plugin and not the WordPress plugin) and for whatever reason the image transitions are HORRIBLE.

Like, they're slow and choppy and you see the transition effect until the image changes again. This is what I mean:

[image]

Here is my jQuery code

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {  

    var logo_width = jQuery('.logo a img').width();
    jQuery('.logo').width(logo_width);

    jQuery('#cycler').nivoSlider({
        effect: 'fade', // Specify sets like: 'fold,fade,sliceDown'
        slices: 15, // For slice animations
        boxCols: 6, // For box animations
        boxRows: 2, // For box animations
        animSpeed: 500, // Slide transition speed
        pauseTime: 3000, // How long each slide will show
        startSlide: 0, // Set starting Slide (0 index)
        directionNav: true, // Next & Prev navigation

        controlNav: true, // 1,2,3... navigation
        controlNavThumbs: false, // Use thumbnails for Control Nav

        manualAdvance: false, // Force manual transitions
        prevText: 'Prev', // Prev directionNav text
        nextText: 'Next', // Next directionNav text
        randomStart: false, // Start on a random slide
    });
});
```

Comment: Can you post your HTML, and do you have any JavaScript errors? using just jQuery('#cycler').nivoSlider(); do you get the weird transitions?

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, there's nothing obvious wrong with your code there - apart from the fact you've used `jQuery(document).ready(function() {`

This might be the issue, document.ready() will run before all the images have been downloaded, so you are running the slider transitions (potentially) while the images are still being downloaded.

I would use `jQuery(window).load(function() {` instead.

Also, there's a trailing comma at the end of your arguments list.   Thsi won't be causing the sluggishness issue but it will cause it to fail in IE7 (if that's an issue for you).

Comment: I don't think this is the issue, he would be seeing completely different problems, not visual errors. i.e. he would see all of them stacked on top of each other (css issue).

Comment: Ah Ok, thanks for the info - it's an odd one, I''ve never had that. I wonder if there are other scripts which are guzzling resources  and preventing the animation playing smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

You need remove all object tag wrapped images in your slide.

Example:
**from**

```
<ul id="slider">
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
<li><img src="..." /></li>
</ul>
```

**to**

```
<div id="slider">
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
<img src="..." />
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm very late to the party here but I had this same issue and managed to sort it.

It turned out it was related to the slices setting. Notice how your slices are set to 15 and there are 15 segments in the "transition" If you set slices to 1, you should be able to sort this.

Took me ages to work out what was going on when it happened to me.